# Angular html5 mode. href causing full page redirect

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular with html5 mode and I am noticing an issue with anchor tags with the href set. If I am on the root ('/'), and I click on an anchor of the form

```
<a href="/entity/233b430e-ef50-4405-b46a-d7de5c235d4a">entity 1</a>
```

(So no target's etc!) will cause a page redirect, instead of just inserting the template into ng-view.

It works just fine if I use the `$location` provider, or set html5mode to false.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong?

Here is an example of my route for the above

```
$routeProvider
.
.
.
    .when('/entity/:id',
    {
        templateUrl: function (params) {
            return '/Entity/View/' + params.id;
        },
        resolve: {
            entityObj: ['$route', 'entityService', function ($route, entityService) {
                var id = $route.current.params.id;
                return entityService.getEntity(id);
            }]
        },
        controller: 'entityViewCtrl',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    })
. 
.
.
```

Comment: Have you tried Angular UI-Router? It

Comment: The stateProvider? I have heard of it :) Since I cannot get this to work, I will give that a go then!